# How to increase some additional pixels in a class property that I want to use for another class using Sass

Tags: css, sass

i have a class

```
.scrollable_container{height:calc(100% - 130px);-webkit-height:calc(100% - 130px);-moz-height:calc(100% - 130px);-ms-height:calc(100% - 130px);
```

and I want to use this class's height properties with 60px more in another class in sass.

i.e

```
.scrollable_container2{height:calc(100% - 190px);-webkit-height:calc(100% - 190px);-moz-height:calc(100% - 190px);-ms-height:calc(100% - 190px);
```

Want above to use math or any other way (Mixin, variable or inheritance)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could work with a mixin:

```
@mixin scrollable-container-style($height) {
    height:calc(100% - $height);
    -webkit-height:calc(100% - $height);
    -moz-height:calc(100% - $height);
    -ms-height:calc(100% - $height);
}

.scrollable_container {
    @include scrollable-container-style(130px);
}

.scrollable_container2 {
    @include scrollable-container-style(190px);
}
```

Comment: I am getting actual value with this

`@mixin scrollable-container-style($height) {
    -webkit-height: calc(100% - #{$height});
     -moz-height: calc(100% - #{$height});
      -ms-height: calc(100% - #{$height});
   height: calc(100% - #{$height});
}`

Comment: Hi, i am not sure what you mean. If you include that like in my answer it should work.